# Prove that if a finite solvable group is simple, it is a cyclic group of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

Prove that if a finite solvable group is simple, it is a cyclic group of prime order.

Help me some hints.

Comment: A detailed answer can be found here http://finitesimple.blogspot.com/2013/01/solvable-simple-groups-have-prime-order.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $[G, G] \triangleleft G$, and
- $[G, G] \neq G$ for a solvable group $G \neq 1$ (why?).